# Tkinter: How can you uniquely color the outline of rectangle created using create_rectangle()?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using:

```
self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill=fill, outline=outline)
```

to create rectangles but all 4 of my outlines are fixed to 1 color. Is there a way set it, for example, for the top and bottom border to be white; and left and right border to be black.

Thanks :)

I tried reading the create_rectange() documentation but I don't find that specific detail.

Comment: If you have read the document, you should know that it does not support what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`create_rectangle` doesn’t support multiple colors for the outline. You will need to use four individual lines if you want to color each edge separately.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try it adding individual lines.